# Locate a Notation that takes an infix argument

Tags: coq

In the `Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.ZModulo.ZModulo` [library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.Cyclic.ZModulo.ZModulo.html), there is the following notation:

```
Notation "[+| c |]" :=
   (interp_carry 1 wB to_Z c) (at level 0, c at level 99).
```

How can I search this? I tried

```
Locate "[+| _ |]".  (* Unknown Notation *)
Locate "[+| |]".    (* Unknown Notation *)
Locate "[+| _ |]".  (* Unknown Notation *)
Locate "[+| c |]".  (* Unknown Notation *)
Locate "[+| ?c |]". (* Unknown Notation *)
Locate [+| ?c |].   (* Error: Syntax error: 'Ltac' or [locatable] expected after 'Locate' (in [vernac:command]). *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first and fourth choices, `Locate "[+| _ |]"`, `Locate "[+| c |]".` are both correct. Note that the variable name doesn't matter: you could do `Locate "[+| abcdef |]".` too.

Note, however, that the particular notation you refer to is inside a section. [This means](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#persistence-of-notations) that it's inaccessible outside the section. In particular, `Locate` won't find it. To test this, try this code:

```
Section ZModulo.
  Notation "[+| c |]" := (S c).

  Locate "[+| _ |]".
  (* Notation
     "[+| c |]" := S c (default interpretation) *)

  Locate "[+| c |]".
  (* Notation
     "[+| c |]" := S c (default interpretation) *)

  Locate "[+| abcdef |]".
  (* Notation
     "[+| c |]" := S c (default interpretation) *)
End ZModulo.

Locate "[+| _ |]". (* Unknown notation *)
Locate "[+| c |]". (* Unknown notation *)
Locate "[+| abcdef |]". (* Unknown notation *)
```

In versions of Coq earlier than 8.8.0, only the first version will work. In 8.8.0, `Locate` [was updated](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.8.0/CHANGES#L44-L45) to allow the other form.

Comment: In old versions (<= 8.7), this only works with an underscore (`"[+| _ |]"`), but your solution indeed works in later versions (>= 8.8).

Comment: @eponier Thanks for the information. I've updated the answer.